# Dividing Doubles in swift by 100

Tags: swift

```
var a:Double = 7599
var b:Double = 7598

var x = a / 100 (75.98999999999999)
var y = b / 100 (75.98)
```

Can anyone tell me why `y` is calculating to 2 decimal places and more importantly why `x` isn't?

I basically use this function in a RoundUp and RoundDown function but it doesn't work for certain numbers.

Comment: Because a and b are different.

Comment: Spend some quality time reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: This is due to the nature of [floating point arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). (Even heavier reading)